# Saving huge number of columns data from Spark RDD(JSON) to Cassandra Table

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

We are trying to create a apache Kafka spark streaming application and saving RDD data to Cassandra. We are sending JSON. object in Kafka producer topic to consumer and able to consume it as well.

But facing issues while saving this JSON data in RDD to Cassandra tables.

**Producer Code:**

```
package com.test.anna.KafkaSpark;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import scala.Array;
import scala.Product;
//import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import scala.collection.Iterator;

public class ProducerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/Users/srikanth_kopparthy/Documents/keystore/client_jaas.conf");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

        properties.put("acks", "all");
        properties.put("retries", "0");
        properties.put("batch.size", "16384");
        properties.put("linger.ms", "1");
        properties.put("request.timeout.ms", "150000");
        properties.put("buffer.memory", "33554432");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        //properties.put("partitioner.class", "SimplePartitioner");
       // properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", ProductsSerializer.class.getName());
        Producer producer = new KafkaProducer(properties);

        //JDBC Connection
     // JDBC driver name and database URL
         String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";  
         String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oogway.corp.xyz.com:1976:cd";

        //  Database credentials
        String USER = "xyzzy";
         String PASS = "pwd";

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
           //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

           //STEP 3: Open a connection
           System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

           //STEP 4: Execute a query
           System.out.println("Creating statement...");
           stmt = conn.createStatement();
           String sql;
           sql = "select * from AP_SALESWS_COMP_CM WHERE ROWNUM <= 10";
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

           //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
           while(rs.next()){
              //Retrieve by column name
             String bo_id  = rs.getString("BO_ID");
              String profile_cm_seq  = rs.getString("PROFILE_CM_SEQ");
              String bo_cm_start_dt  = rs.getString("BO_CM_START_DT");


//              List<String> listColumn=new ArrayList<>();
//              listColumn.add(bo_id);
//              listColumn.add(profile_cm_seq);
//              listColumn.add(bo_cm_start_dt);
              Products product=new Products();
              product.setId(bo_id);
              product.setName(profile_cm_seq);
              product.setParents(bo_cm_start_dt);

              String bo_cm_end_dt  = rs.getString("END_DT");
              String cm_id  = rs.getString("ID");

              //Display values
              System.out.print("ID: " + id);

                 // String msg = "Testing : Published Message from sample Producer Client " + i;
                //  Future response = producer.send(new ProducerRecord("test6","BID "+ bid + "  " +"PRFIE SEQ " + profle__seq + "   " + "START DATE " + start_dt + "    " + "END DATE " + end_dt + "    " + "CM ID " + cm_id));
              Future response = producer.send(new ProducerRecord("test7", bo_id,product));
                  try {
                    response.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    while(response.isDone()) {
                        System.out.println(response.get().toString());
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Sent:" + bo_id);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted exception..");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                    System.out.println("execution exception..");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e1) {
                    System.out.println("TimeoutException..");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



           }
           //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
           rs.close();
           stmt.close();
           conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
           //Handle errors for JDBC
           se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
           //Handle errors for Class.forName
           e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
           //finally block used to close resources
           try{
              if(stmt!=null)
                 stmt.close();
           }catch(SQLException se2){
           }// nothing we can do
           try{
              if(conn!=null)
                 conn.close();
           }catch(SQLException se){
              se.printStackTrace();
           }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");

        //JDBC Connection END






    }

}
```

**Consumer Code:**

```
package com.test.anna.KafkaSpark;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.*;
import  com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*;
import  com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.*;
import  com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.DStreamJavaFunctions.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.function.Function;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory$;
import org.apache.commons.collections.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;

import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.reflect.macros.internal.macroImpl;  
i

public class SparkStreamingConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost"); //for cassandra
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(20000));

        // TODO: processing pipeline
        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect","localhost:2181");
        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("test7");
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);




        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            System.out.println("Message Received "+rdd.values().take(1));
            System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.partitions().size()
                + " partitions and " + rdd.count() + " records");
            rdd.foreach(record -> System.out.println(record));
           JavaRDD<String> rdd2=rdd.map(x ->(x._2));
          // JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>> c1 = rdd2.mapToPair(i -> new Tuple2(i._1()));
            System.out.println("rdd output----"+rdd.collect());
            System.out.println("rdd2 output--"+ rdd2.collect());
        //    System.out.println("rdd2 output afeter update--"+ c1.collect());
           System.out.println("writing to cassandra");

           jsonR

         // JavaPairRDD<String,String> newRdd2= JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(rdd2) ;

          // CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rdd2).writerBuilder("java_api3", "products", CassandraJavaUtil.mapTupleToRow(String.class,String.class,String.class)).saveToCassandra();

       //  CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rdd,Products.class).writerBuilder("java_api3", "products",CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(Products.class)).saveToCassandra();

         //  CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rdd2).writerBuilder("java_api3", "products", CassandraJavaUtil.mapTupleToRow(String.class,String.class,String.class)).withColumnSelector(CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("id", "name","parents")).saveToCassandra(); 


      CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("java_api3", "products", CassandraJavaUtil.mapTupleToRow(String.class,String.class)).withColumnSelector(CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("id", "name")).saveToCassandra(); 




        });



        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();



    }   
}
```

Kindly let us know how to handle JSON in spark strreaming so that we can save it in Cassandra tables directly.

And how can we convert JAVARDD to JavaPairRDD in java.

Note: We are writing the app code in Java, not using scala at all.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can learn from here http://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2016/01/30/processing-json-data-with-sparksql/

Comment: are you sure about json data properly formatted, I mean is there a new line at the the end of the or string. Please double check this, I have faced the same while I am doing spark

Comment: I can help you with this.